# How can we know that the decimal expansion of an irrational number will never repeat?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we know that the decimal expansion of an irrational number will never repeat? For example what if the value of π after some quintillions of digits start repeating.

Comment: We know that $\pi$ is irrational so there cannot be any "patterns" in its decimal representation (loosely).  Your question might really be "why must rational numbers terminate or have repeating blocks in their decimal expansion?"

Comment: We have proofs, that's how we know.

Comment: if you have periodic decimal or one that terminates, it is a rational number.

Comment: The proof that $\pi $ is irrational is not straight forward.  If you are just starting in with the subject, I suggest starting with the proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. 
 See, e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2).

Comment: To see that a number with periodic decimal expansion is rational use geometric series!

Comment: It seems to me that @Blue's edit changed the question from "How do we know that $\pi$ is irrational?" to "How do we know that an irrational number never repeats?"

Comment: @TonyK: If you check the Edit History, you'll find that the original title was "Are irrational numbers really irrational?". This seemed somewhat vague to me, so I edited it to reflect the more-specific phrasing provided in the body of the post.

Comment: @Blue: I think you misunderstood the OP's intent. But I suppose only the OP can clear this up for us.

Answer (score 1):

If there appears a period in the decimal expansion of a number then You have after subtracting a rational term an expression of the form
$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(d_1...d_r)10^{-rn}$$
where $d_j\in\{0,...,9\}$ are the digits in the period and $r$ its length. Clearly this expression is rational if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(d_1...d_r)10^{-rn}$ is rational and 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(d_1...d_r)10^{-rn}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{d_1...d_r}{10^r}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{d_1...d_r}{10^r}}$$
is rational as a geometric series. Note $\frac{d_1...d_r}{10^r}<1$. Since there are (quite sophisticated) proofs that $\pi$ is irrational (even transcendental, i.e. no root of any polynomial with rational coefficients,) one concludes that its decimal expansion cannot lead to any period.

Answer (score 0):

Here are [proofs that $\pi$ is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational).

Here are [proofs that $\sqrt2$ is irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality).

Basically, to show that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, you can assume that it has the form $\frac pq$ with $p$ and $q$ coprime; then you can write this as $2p^2=q^2$, infer that $q$ is even, write $q=2k$ and get $p^2=2k^2$, from which you can infer that $p$ is even, contradicting the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are coprime.

To see that a real number with a repeating decimal expansion is rational, note e.g. $0.\overline{abc}=\frac{abc}{999}$.

Comment: How does this relate to the decimal expansion of $\pi$ and $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: @SantanaAfton: A real number is rational if and only if its decimal expansion is terminating or repeating; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal#Every_repeating_or_terminating_decimal_is_a_rational_number). The original title of the question was "Are irrational numbers really irrational" and didn't focus on decimal expansions.